# Change column color in Oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

How can I change the background color of every second column using interactive report.

[image: I have 4 column. Second column must have a blue color and the 4 column must have red color]

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend using css. If you don't like CSS just go directly to IR section in my answer

### CSS

```
th:nth-child(even),
td:nth-child(even){
  background-color: red !important
}
```

or

```
th:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red !important
}

th:nth-child(4),    
td:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: blue !important
}
```

or

```
th#C152380905075548116,
td[headers="C152380905075548116"] {
  background-color: red !important;
}

th#C152381026269548117,    
td[headers="C152381026269548117"] {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

where `C152380905075548116` and `C152381026269548117` are columns id that should be replaced.

### IR

If you really need to use native IR functionalities you should follow 3 steps:

1. Change report SQL query so the column contains name of the color you want to use as background

eg:

```
select
  ...
  VALUE1||'<span style="display: none">red</red>' as Artikl
  VALUE2||'<span style="display: none">blue</red>' as "Broj gresaka"
  ..
from
  ..
```

2. Add IR highlights `Actions > Format > Highlight`

> Name = Red background (Artikl)
>
> Sequence = Sequence
>
> Enabled = Yes
>
> Highlight Type = Cell
>
> Background Color  = #FF7755
>
> Text Color = null
>
> Column = Artikl
>
> Operator = Contains
>
> Expression = red

and

> Name = Blue background (Broj gresaka)
>
> Sequence = Sequence
>
> Enabled = Yes
>
> Highlight Type = Cell
>
> Background Color  = #99CCFF
>
> Text Color = null
>
> Column = Artikl
>
> Operator = Contains
>
> Expression = blue

3. Set columns attribute `Security > Escape special characters` to `No`

It is not the perfect solution but it works :-)